# Python pandas remove duplicate rows that have a column value "NaN"

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

The need to rows that have NaN values in them but are also duplicates. For example this table:

```
    A   B   C
0   foo 2   3
1   foo nan nan
2   foo 1   4
3   bar nan nan
4   foo nan nan
```

Should become this:

```
    A   B   C
0   foo 2   3
2   foo 1   4
3   bar nan nan
```

How can i do that?

Comment: drop_duplicates doesnt drop different column values and drop_na drops every column with nan values. I need to drop every duplicate of a specific column where the row has a NaN value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~df['A'].duplicated(keep=False) | df[['B','C']].notnull().any(axis=1)]
print (df)
     A    B    C
0  foo  2.0  3.0
2  foo  1.0  4.0
3  bar  NaN  NaN
```

**Explanation**:

Test column `A` for not duplicates - [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `~` for invert boolean mask:

```
print (~df['A'].duplicated(keep=False))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Check non missing values in `B,C` columns:

```
print (df[['B','C']].notnull())
       B      C
0   True   True
1  False  False
2   True   True
3  False  False
4  False  False
```

And then at least one True per row with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print (df[['B','C']].notnull().any(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Chain together by `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
print (~df['A'].duplicated(keep=False) | df[['B','C']].notnull().any(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different to jezrael's solution:

```
>>> df                                                                                                     
     A    B    C
0  foo  2.0  3.0
1  foo  NaN  NaN
2  foo  1.0  4.0
3  bar  NaN  NaN
4  foo  NaN  NaN
>>>
>>> df.drop(index=df[df.duplicated(keep=False)].isnull().any(1).index)                                  
     A    B    C
0  foo  2.0  3.0
2  foo  1.0  4.0
3  bar  NaN  NaN
```

Steps:

```
>>> df.duplicated(keep=False)                                                                            
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
>>>
>>> df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]                                                                       
      A   B   C
1  foo NaN NaN
4  foo NaN NaN
>>>
>>> df[df.duplicated(keep=False)].isnull()                                                                 
       A     B     C
1  False  True  True
4  False  True  True
>>>
>>> df[df.duplicated(keep=False)].isnull().any(1).index                                                          
Int64Index([1, 4], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: If you downvoted this answer, I would appreciate if you left a comment such that I can improve the answer.